# Consumo Web Service Soap Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, soap, net

Estoy realizando el consumo de un web service Soap desde JavaScript, el consumo finaliza satisfactoriamente y me devuelve la respuesta pero no logro mostrarla en pantalla.
El código es el siguiente:

```
function ObtenerToken() {  
  var usuario, contrasena;
  usuario = document.forms["form1"].txtUsuario.value;
  contrasena = document.forms["form1"].txtContrasena.value;

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:1750/wsPruebas.asmx?op=Autentitacion', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
  var sr =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
    '<soap:Envelope ' +
    'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
    'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ' +
    'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> ' +
    '<soap:Body> ' +
    '<Autentitacion xmlns="http://www.pruebas.com.co/"> ' +
    '<Usuario>' + usuario + '</Usuario>' +
    '<Contrasena>' + contrasena + '</Contrasena>' +
    '</Autentitacion> ' +
    '</soap:Body> ' +
    '</soap:Envelope>';

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      var spn = document.getElementById("lblMensaje");
      spn.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
      var sRespuesta;
      sRespuesta = document.getElementById("lblMensaje").textContent;         
      alert("Respuesta " + sRespuesta);          
    }
  }
  xhr.send(sr);      
  return false;
}
```

En el alert me muestra la respuesta pero quiero moverlo a un Textbox para luego trabajar con el.

Comment: Agrega que te retorna el xhr. Ej: __Console.log(xhr)__

Comment: Hola, es que si obtengo la respuesta y la muevo a un label y luego lo muestro en un alert (alert("Respuesta " + sRespuesta);   ) pero luego de finalizar el proceso el Label queda sin valor entonces no puedo trabajar con el.

Comment: Si por eso te estoy pidiendo que agregues un ejemplo de cómo llega el objeto para poder ayudarte

Comment: Hola, al impimir "console.log("Respuesta: ", sRespuesta);" nos muestra "Respuesta:  4f323d6e03d421181c3fe42287f5fae02497d7ce"